# Ansible: with_sequence variable start and end

Tags: ansible

In my playbook I supply a Jenkins build ID as follows:
`-e frontend_build_id=43`

This ID is used to tag Docker images created during the build process. Later I want to remove old images as follows:

```
- name: remove old frontend images
  docker_image:
    state: absent
    name: "{{ docker_registry }}/{{ frontend_image_name }}"
    tag: "{{ item }}"
    force: yes
    with_sequence:
      start="{{ frontend_build_id }} - 10" end="{{ frontend_build_id }} - 1" stride=1
```

However I get following error:

```
TASK [FrontEnd : remove old frontend images] ***********************************
fatal: [10.98.68.116]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/jenkins/workspace/myproject_development/roles/FrontEnd/tasks/main.yml': line 31, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: remove old frontend images\n  ^ here\n"}
```

1. What do I do wrong?
2. Maybe its better to achieve this with `loop` somehow?

Comment: "with_sequence:" needs to be intended properly, under "docker_image"!

Comment: You are able to edit the question. It's better to correct the code in the question and delete the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the sequence you're looking for?

```yaml
 with_sequence:
   start="{{ frontend_build_id - 10 }}" end="{{ frontend_build_id - 1 }}" stride=1
```

The default of '*stride*' is 1. For simplicity, it can be removed.

```yaml
 with_sequence:
   start="{{ frontend_build_id - 10 }}" end="{{ frontend_build_id - 1 }}"
```

[Loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence) '*range*' will do the same. The end element is not inclusive and shall be incremented.

```yaml
 loop: "{{ range(frontend_build_id - 10, frontend_build_id)|list }}"
```

The explicit cast of the variable '*frontend_build_id*' to the integer will make it more robust. Change each reference to '*frontend_build_id*' to '*frontend_build_id|int*'. For example:

```yaml
 with_sequence:
   start="{{ frontend_build_id|int - 10 }}" end="{{ frontend_build_id|int - 1 }}"
```

This should probably solve the problem

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'int'

Comment: Thanks, but with the loop I get: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ range(frontend_build_id - 10, frontend_build_id - 3)|list }}): unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'int'"}

Comment: start="{{ frontend_build_id | int - 10 }}" or start="{{ frontend_build_id - 10 | int }}" ?